# Oracle APEX - Reusable Pages?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

We have some tables in our database that all have the same attributes but the table is named differently for each.  I'm not sure of the Architect's original intent in creating them in this way, but this is what I have to work with.

My question for all the expert Oracle APEX developers: is there away to create a reusable page that I can pass the table name to and that table name would be used in the reporting region and DML processing of that page?

I've read up on templates and plugins and don't see a path forward with those options.  Of course, I'm new to webdevelopment, so forgive my ignorance.

We are using version 18.2.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Are you planning on using insert, update, or delete? Or are you simply displaying the data from the table?

Answer (score 2):

For reporting purposes, you could use a source which is a function that returns a query (i.e. a `SELECT` statement). Doing so, you'd *dynamically* decide which table to select from.

However, DML isn't that simple. Instead of *default* row processing, you should write your own process(es) so that you'd insert/update/delete rows in the right table. I've never done that, but I'd say that it is possible. Basically, you'd keep all logic in the database (for example, a package) and call those procedures from your Apex application.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot!  I did think about this method and will consider it.  I was attempting to see if there was some other way that kept the default DML processing.  Thanks again for your post.

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple regions on one page; one region per table.  Then use dynamic actions to show/hide the regions and run the select query based on a table name selected by the user.

1. Select table name from a dropdown or list
2. Show the region that matches the table name (dynamic action)
3. Hide the any other regions that are visible (dynamic action)
4. Refresh the selected region so the data loads (dynamic action)

If that idea works let me know and I can provide a bit more guidance.

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper!  This may show promise, but our DB Architect may have found a workaround through parent/child relationship within the database architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it with reports, but would it work to put all three reports in a single page, and set them via an Item to have Server-Side Conditions that decide what gets shown in the page? You'd likely need separate items with a determined value for the page to recognize and display.

I know I did that to set buttons such as Delete, Save and Create dynamically, rather than creating two or more separate pages for handling editing of certain information. In this case it regarded which buttons to shown based on a reports' primary key being sent to said "Edit" page. If the value was empty, it meant you wanted to create a new record (also because the create button/link sent no PK). If said PK was sent (via a edit button/link), then you'd have the page recognize it and hide the create button and rather show the edit button.